# Remove red * in required fields Yiibooster

Tags: yii, yii-extensions, yii-booster

I'm using yiibooster and it is really good extension for the frontend, my issues now is that I want to remove the red * that is rendered in the required fields but maintaining the required validator in the model, anyone knows how to do this????

thankss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to achieve what you want **easily**, I suggest you to do like below, which is simplest way(in my view point):

Just try to find `*` selector(the `ID` or `CLASS`) name.(using a firebug or any inspector)
Then just do like below in your `document.ready()`:

```
$(SELECTOR).remove();
```

**NOTES**

- THE `*` MIGHT BE CREATED DYNAMICALLY
- THIS IS JUST AN SUGGESTION, YOU CAN FIND ANY OTHER POSSIBLE WAYS SUCH AS `CHANGING THE CSS CLASS` IN ORDER TO DO `DISPLAY:NONE` OR `SOURCE MODIFICATION`

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of a label generated by a required field validator:

```
<label for="User_email" class="required">
    Email Address <span class="required">*</span>
</label>
```

Therefore, you can hide it by adding this class to your site's CSS:

```
span.required {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo $form->textFieldGroup($model, 'username',array('label'=>Yii::t('model','Username'))); ?>
```

or edit **line 1223  of TbActiveForm.php** from

```
echo $this->labelEx($model, $attribute, $options['labelOptions']);
```

to

```
echo $this->label($model, $attribute, $options['labelOptions']);
```

Comment: This is the best answer in this question.

Answer (score 0):

`Red *` is adding according to your validators definition in your model. you have two options. 
**First** in your model add `On => 'scenario name'` for `required validator` for the property you want. so you can control the behavior of yii-booster components because they only apply those rules which matches the `scenario` of the model. for example:

```
array('password_repeat', 'required', 'on'=>'register'),
```

It will show `Red *` only in `register` scenario (if you set it via `$model->setScenario('register');`) and in normal times no `red *` will shown.

**Another** option for you is when you are creating the form element based on the property marked `required` by validator rules in model, you can prevent that `*` from showing but this way will not ignore that `validation rule` and if you try to submit the form while this form field is empty you will get error from yii (because you just solve showing but in background you have your required validator). for this method, you only need to provide `label` in your `yii-booster` form element:

```
<?php echo $form->textFieldGroup($model,'textField',
            array(
                'wrapperHtmlOptions' => array(
                    'class' => 'col-sm-5',
                ),
                'hint' => 'In addition to freeform text, any HTML5 text-based input appears like so.',
         >>>>>  'label' => 'Your new value for label which will have no red *',
            )
        ); ?>
```